# PHP Function to generate an infinite unique indentifier

Tags: php, security, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-framework3

I'm making a new project in Zend 3 that requires me to have a unique ID or HASH which I can use in several places later.

I looked at many examples on Google, and could not find a function that can satisfy my requirements because this needs to be 99% unique all the time, and it needs to be able to generate hundreds, millions of "hashes" unique all the time.

The following function caught my attention:

```
  function uniqidReal($lenght = 13) {
        // uniqid gives 13 chars, but you could adjust it to your needs.
        if (function_exists("random_bytes")) {
            $bytes = random_bytes(ceil($lenght / 2));
        } elseif (function_exists("openssl_random_pseudo_bytes")) {
            $bytes = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(ceil($lenght / 2));
        } else {
            throw new Exception("no cryptographically secure random function available");
        }
        return substr(bin2hex($bytes), 0, $lenght);
    }
```

A simple test:

```
echo "<pre>";

for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++)
{
    echo $this->uniqidReal(25) .PHP_EOL ;   
}
```

The result:

```
a8ba1942ad99d09f496d3d564
5b24746d09cada4b2dc9816bd
c6630c35bc9b4ed0907c803e0
48e04958b633e8a5ead137bb1
643a4ce1bcbca66cea397e85e
d2cd4c6f8dc7054dd0636075f
d9c78bae38720b7e0cc6361f2
54e5f852862adad2ad7bc3349
16c4e42e4f63f62bf9653f96e
c63d64af261e601e4b124e38f
29a3efa07a4d77406349e3020
107d78fdfca13571c152441f2
591b25ebdb695c8259ccc7fe9
105c4f2cc5266bb82222480ba
84e9ad8fd76226f86c89c1ac1
39381d31f494d320abc538a8e
7f8141db50a41b15a85599548
7b15055f6d9fb1228b7438d2a
659182c7bcd5b050befd3fc4c
06f70d134a3839677caa0d246
600b15c9dc53ef7a4551b8a90
a9c8af631c5361e8e1e1b8d9d
4b4b0aca3bbf15d35dd7d1050
f77024a07ee0dcee358dc1f5e
408c007b9d771718263b536e1
2de08e01684805a189224db75
c3838c034ae22d21f27e5d040
b15e9b0bab6ef6a56225a5983
251809396beb9d24b384f5fe8
cec6d262803311152db31b723
95d271ffdfe9df5861eefbaa4
7c11f3401530790b9ef510e55
e363390e2829097e7762bddc4
7ef34c69d9b8e38d72c6db29f
309a84490a7e387aaff1817ca
c214af2927c683954894365df
9f70859880b7ffa4b28265dbb
608e2f2f9e38025d92a1a4f03
c457a54d2da30a4a517edf14c
8670acbded737b1d2febdd954
99899b74b6469e366122b658c
3066408f5b4e86ef84bdb3fb9
010715f4955f66da3402bfa7b
fa01675690435b914631b46e1
2c5e234c5868799f31a6c983c
8345da31809ab2d9714a01d05
7b4e0e507dd0a8b6d7170a265
5aa71aded9fe7afa9a93a98c5
3714fb9f061398d4bb6af909d
165dd0af233cce64cefec12ed
849dda54070b868b50f356068
fe5f6e408eda6e9d429fa34ed
cd13f8da95c5b92b16d9d2781
65d0f69b41ea996ae2f8783a5
5742caf7a922eb3aaa270df30
f381ac4b84f3315e9163f169e
8c2afa1ab32b6fe402bf97ba3
a9f431efe6fc98aa64dbecbc2
8f0746e4e9529326d087f828b
bfc3cbea4d7f5c4495a14fc49
e4bf2d1468c6482570612360e
f1c7238766acdb7f199049487
60ae8a1ffd6784f7bbbc7b437
30afd67f207de6e893f7c9f42
dfa151daccb0e8d64d100f719
07be6a7d4aab21ccd9942401b
73ca1a54fcc40f7a46f46afbd
94ed2888fb93cb65d819d9d52
b7317773c6a15aa0bdf25fa01
edbb7f20f7523d9d941f3ebce
99a3c204b9f2036d3c38342bb
a0585424b8ab2ffcabee299d5
64e669fe2490522451cf10f85
18b8be34d4c560cda5280a103
9524d1f024b3c9864a3fccf75
0e7e94e7974894c98442241bc
4a17cc5e3d2baabaa338f592e
b070eaf38f390516f5cf61aa7
cc7832ea327b7426d8d2b8c2b
0df0a1d4833ebbb5d463c56bf
1bb610a8bb4e241996c9c756a
34ac2fdeb4b88fe6321a1d9c3
f0b20f8e79090dcb65195524c
307252efdd2b833228e0c301f
3908e63b405501782e629ac0b
29e66717adf14fb30c626103d
c8abd48af5f9332b322dffad0
80cd4e162bc7e8fb3a756b48c
825c00cec2294061eb328dd97
106205a2e24609652d149bc17
f1f896657fbc6f6287e7dee20
0fbd16ade658e24d69f76a225
4ab3b5eeeda86fa81afba796a
11d34f3d2ffb61d55da560ddb
013d6151bad187906fcc579a4
4509279a28f34bcf5327dd4c0
3c0eb47b3f9dc5a2f794bb9ad
1e6506906f23542c889330836
e7b1c5012390f3c7c48def9f3
d86caa695cb5fa1e0a2ead4cc
```

But I cannot confirm that this does guarantee me a 99% success rate for my production environment.

If someone can advise me, or provide me an example I would much appreciate it!

Comment: you have to safe your ids if you want guarantee that they are unique. but what if you include the microtime? `microtime().$yourKey` Will that be enough?

Comment: @user2659982 - That won't do it unfortunately... Have a look at CloudFlare -> Zone ID for example, they have a ton of websites with each different unique Zone ID...

Comment: They save them in a database and then you can look for it while generating an unique id

Comment: Well I am planning to store it in a database, so I can use it later

Comment: Concatenate the autoincrement from the database with a random hash and it will always be unique and random :)

Comment: Heuristically, you cannot generate an infinite number of random numbers because your data type is 13 bytes. That limits the range of number of random numbers from `0` to `2**(13*8) - 1`.

Comment: @jww - I changed the number to 35 and I tested with hundreds of randomly generated "hashes"... all 35 length.

Comment: @Johan - Thanks, I will keep that in mind!

Comment: Maybe UUID4 maybe helpfully for you. There is many libraries in packagist.org supported that algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `random_bytes` generates cryptographically secure random bytes

For `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` add the `crypto_strong` paramdeter to ensure the algorithm used is cryptographically strong.

Since your requirement is only 99% unique cryptographically secure random bytes will meet your requirement.

Comment: Thank you, and the crypto_strong should be ?

Comment: See [openssl_random_pseudo_bytes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php): *If `crypto_strong` is passed into the function, this will hold a boolean value that determines if the algorithm used was "cryptographically strong", TRUE if it did, otherwise FALSE*.

Comment: Thank you, I will go with this function.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment, but its a bit long.

There is some confusion over your use of "unique" and "all the time". A token is either unique or it is not. Using a random number generator to create tokens alone is not sufficient to guarantee uniqueness - the whole point of a random number generator is that you don't know what the next value to be generated will be - meaning you also don't know that the next number won't be the same as a previous number. OTOH, using random_bytes() or openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() to generate a token which is "99% unique all the time" seems like a massive overkill.

To work out how unique this is likely to be we would need to know how many tokens will be considered within the populations at any one time (or to be able to calculate this from the expected rate of creation and the TTL).

That you are using large numbers rather implies you have a very good reason for not using the simplest and most obvious unique identifier - i.e. an incrementing integer. Hence the resistance to guessing an existing identifier is clearly critical to the implementation - but again you've told us nothing about that.

Pasting the title of your post into Google turns up your post as the top result - with [PHP's uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)() function immediately after it - yet for some reason you've either not found uniqid() or have rejected it for some reason.

The title of your post is also an oxymoron - In order to define an infinite set of identifiers, the identifiers would need to be of infinite length.

> it needs to be able to generate hundreds, millions of "hashes"

....and you want it all to run within the Zend Framework? - LOL.

> But I cannot confirm that this does guarantee me a 99% success rate for my production environment.

Why not? You have sufficient information here to confirm that the bitwise entropy is evenly distributed and should know the planned capacity of the production environment. The rest is basic arithmetic.

Comment: I rejected uniqid() because it cannot guarantee it`s functionality, please read and see for yourself php.net - also I might not have explained myself good enough, by "it needs to be able to generate hundreds, millions of "hashes"" ...

Comment: If you are are not in a position to measure the effectiveness of the random number approach you cited, how can you measure the effectiveness of uniqid() ?

Comment: As PHP.net say: "This function does not guarantee uniqueness of return value. Since most systems adjust system clock by NTP or like, system time is changed constantly. Therefore, it is possible that this function does not return unique ID for the process/thread. Use more_entropy to increase likelihood of uniqueness."

Comment: You've already said you don't need the value to be unique *all the time*.

Comment: You're measure of quality is that some random person on the internet said so?

Comment: I think you did either not read or understand what I want, yes it needs to be UNIQUE all the time, and the number of possible generations needs to be infinite, EG: Never make the same value twice. And that text I quoted is not a random person, is from the php.net website...

Answer (score 1):

We are about 8x10⁹ people. Imagine all us access your site once each second needing a unique identifier during a year. You need about 2,52288×10²³ identifiers. If you think your site will be in production about 1000 years, and population get bigger by a 1000 factor you need about 10²⁹ identifiers; so a 32 bytes auto-incremental string is good enough. Add as suffix a pseudo-random 32 bytes string to get a secure 64 bytes identifier. Doing a bit plus you can hash identifiers to create tokens.

Then is easy to write a function to get them.

Edited 2017/04/13
A small sample:
The first thing you need is a pseudo-random strong keys generator. I'll post the function I'm using currently:

```
<?php
function pseudoRandomBytes($count = 32){
  static $random_state, $bytes, $has_openssl, $has_hash;
  $missing_bytes = $count - strlen($bytes);
  if ($missing_bytes > 0) {
  // If you are using a Php version before 5.3.4 avoid using
  // openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()
    if (!isset($has_openssl)) {
      $has_openssl = version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.4', '>=') 
                   && function_exists('openssl_random_pseudo_bytes');
    }
    // to get entropy
    if ($has_openssl) {
      $bytes .= openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($missing_bytes);
    } elseif ($fh = @fopen('/dev/urandom', 'rb')) {
      // avoiding openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()
      // you find entropy at /dev/urandom usually available in most
      // *nix systems
      $bytes .= fread($fh, max(4096, $missing_bytes));
      fclose($fh);
    }
    // If it fails you must create enough entropy
    if (strlen($bytes) < $count) {
      // Initialize on the first call. The contents of $_SERVER 
      // includes a mix of user-specific and system information 
      // that varies a little with each page.
      if (!isset($random_state)) {
        $random_state = print_r($_SERVER, TRUE);
        if (function_exists('getmypid')) {
          // Further initialize with the somewhat random PHP process ID.
          $random_state .= getmypid();
        }
        // hash() is only available in PHP 5.1.2+ or via PECL.
        $has_hash = function_exists('hash') 
                  && in_array('sha256', hash_algos());
        $bytes = '';
      }
      if ($has_hash) {
        do {
          $random_state = hash('sha256', microtime() . mt_rand() . 
          $random_state);
          $bytes .= hash('sha256', mt_rand() . $random_state, TRUE);
        } while (strlen($bytes) < $count);
      } else {
        do {
          $random_state = md5(microtime() . mt_rand() . $random_state);
          $bytes .= pack("H*", md5(mt_rand() . $random_state));
        } while (strlen($bytes) < $count);
      }
    }
  }
  $output = substr($bytes, 0, $count);
  $bytes = substr($bytes, $count);
  return $output;
}
```

Once you have that function you need a function to create your random keys:

```
<?php
function pseudo_random_key($byte_count = 32) {
  return base64_encode(pseudoRandomBytes($byte_count));
}
```

As **random does not mean unique!** you need to merge a unique 32 bytes prefix as I suggested. As big number functions are time-expensive I'll use a chunk-math function using a prefix I suppose generated from time to time using a cron function and stored at an environment DB variable and an auto-incremental index also db-stored

```
<?php
function uniqueChunkMathKeysPrefix(){
  // a call to read your db for prefix
  // I suppose you have an environment string-keyed table
  // and a couple of dbfunction to read and write data to it
  $last18bytesPrefix = dbReadEnvVariable('unique_prefix');
  // Also you store your current index wich returns to 0 once you get
  // a 99999999999999 value
  $lastuniqueindex = dbReadEnvVariable('last_unique_keys_index');
  if ($lastuniqueindex < 99999999999999){
    $currentuniqueindex = $lastuniqueindex + 1;
    $curret18bytesPrefix = $last18bytesPrefix;
  }else{
    $currentuniqueindex = 0;
    $curret18bytesPrefix = dbReadEnvVariable('next_unique_prefix');
    // flag your db variables to notify cron to create a new next prefix
    dbStoreEnvVariable('next_unique_prefix', 0);
    dbStoreEnvVariable('unique_prefix', $curret18bytesPrefix);
    // you have the time needed to have site visits and create new 
    // 99999999999999 keys as a while to run your cron to adjust your 
    // next prefix
  }
  // store your current index
  dbStoreEnvVariable('last_unique_keys_index', $currentuniqueindex);
  // Finally you create the unique index prefix part
  $uniqueindexchunk = substr('00000000000000'.$currentuniqueindex, -14);
  // return the output
  return $curret18bytesPrefix.$uniqueindexchunk;
}
```

Now you can write a function for unique pseudo-random 64 bytes uniquekeys

```
<?php
function createUniquePseudoRandomKey(){
  $newkey = uniqueChunkMathKeysPrefix() . pseudo_random_key(32);
  // to beautify the output make a dummie call
  // masking the 0s ties
  return md5($newkey);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it does help, but an example would be even better :)